# Django compare passed in value to a variable on the fly

Tags: django

I have the following in my template inside of a table:

```
{% for sb in ship_back %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ sb.ring_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ sb.release.ring }} pp{{ sb.release.ppack }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

This produces the following output:

> Larry 15 pp28
>
> Moe   15 pp29
>
> Curly 15 pp30
>
> Shemp 16 pp7

I would like to add a horizontal line in the table whenever the {{ sb.release.ring }} value changes. In the above example, that would come in between Curly and Shemp.

I would normally create a variable for this outside the for loop, set it's initial value to 0, make a comparison at the beginning of the for loop (ignoring the 0 case) and if it did not match the current value of {{ sb.release.ring }}, I would insert the horizontal line.

I'm struggling to figure out how to accomplish this in Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [`ifchanged`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag, in the following way:

```
{% for sb in ship_back %}

    {# <!-- Style this however you like --> #}
    {% ifchanged sb.release.ring %} 
         <tr><td>----</td></tr>
    {% endifchanged %}

    <tr>
        <td>{{ sb.ring_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ sb.release.ring }} pp{{ sb.release.ppack }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That's almost working for me. It's putting the <hr> before Larry and before Shemp. The latter is appropriate for what I want. I'm guessing that the ifchanged is evaluating nothing becoming something as a change, and that's why it's putting the <hr> there too.

Comment: I was able to get it to work by adding an if statement within the ifchanged block.

{% ifchanged sb.release.ring.ring %} 
    {% if forloop.counter >= 2 %}
        <tr><td colspan=2><hr></td></tr>
    {% endif %} 
{% endifchanged %}

Comment: Unless there's a reason why that's not a good idea as an addition, I'll mark this as the accepted answer.